# Indexing in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to understand how the indexing in the following bit of code works.

```
  i=1
  j=NTAB                                       ! setting up for binary search
  DO
    k=(i+j)/2                                              ! integer division
    IF (h < htab(k)) THEN
      j=k
    ELSE
      i=k
    END IF
    IF (j <= i+1) EXIT
  END DO
```

I feel like this code snippet above is supposed to be a type of loop, but I don't understand how it works. It starts off with i=1 and j=8, leading to k=4.5, leading to a reference in the 4.5th index in the htab array, but this doesn't make any sense to me. I'm trying to translate this snippet of program into Matlab, but I don't know what to do about that small portion. Can someone tell me what this piece of code is doing or translate that small portion of code into Matlab or Python?

Below is the program that snippet above comes from so that you can see the references in the DO command.

```
!+
SUBROUTINE Atmosphere(alt, sigma, delta, theta)
!   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
! PURPOSE - Compute the properties of the 1976 standard atmosphere to 86 km.
! AUTHOR - Ralph Carmichael, Public Domain Aeronautical Software
! NOTE - If alt > 86, the values returned will not be correct, but they will
!   not be too far removed from the correct values for density.
!   The reference document does not use the terms pressure and temperature
!   above 86 km.
  IMPLICIT NONE
!============================================================================
!     A R G U M E N T S                                                     |
!============================================================================
  REAL,INTENT(IN)::  alt        ! geometric altitude, km.
  REAL,INTENT(OUT):: sigma      ! density/sea-level standard density
  REAL,INTENT(OUT):: delta      ! pressure/sea-level standard pressure
  REAL,INTENT(OUT):: theta      ! temperature/sea-level standard temperature
!============================================================================
!     L O C A L   C O N S T A N T S                                         |
!============================================================================
  REAL,PARAMETER:: REARTH = 6369.0                 ! radius of the Earth (km)
  REAL,PARAMETER:: GMR = 34.163195                     ! hydrostatic constant
  INTEGER,PARAMETER:: NTAB=8       ! number of entries in the defining tables
!============================================================================
!     L O C A L   V A R I A B L E S                                         |
!============================================================================
  INTEGER:: i,j,k                                                  ! counters
  REAL:: h                                       ! geopotential altitude (km)
  REAL:: tgrad, tbase      ! temperature gradient and base temp of this layer
  REAL:: tlocal                                           ! local temperature
  REAL:: deltah                             ! height above base of this layer
!============================================================================
!     L O C A L   A R R A Y S   ( 1 9 7 6   S T D.  A T M O S P H E R E )   |
!============================================================================
  REAL,DIMENSION(NTAB),PARAMETER:: htab= &
                          (/0.0, 11.0, 20.0, 32.0, 47.0, 51.0, 71.0, 84.852/)
  REAL,DIMENSION(NTAB),PARAMETER:: ttab= &
          (/288.15, 216.65, 216.65, 228.65, 270.65, 270.65, 214.65, 186.946/)
  REAL,DIMENSION(NTAB),PARAMETER:: ptab= &
               (/1.0, 2.233611E-1, 5.403295E-2, 8.5666784E-3, 1.0945601E-3, &
                                     6.6063531E-4, 3.9046834E-5, 3.68501E-6/)
  REAL,DIMENSION(NTAB),PARAMETER:: gtab= &
                                (/-6.5, 0.0, 1.0, 2.8, 0.0, -2.8, -2.0, 0.0/)
!----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  h=alt*REARTH/(alt+REARTH)      ! convert geometric to geopotential altitude

  i=1
  j=NTAB                                       ! setting up for binary search
  DO
    k=(i+j)/2                                              ! integer division
    IF (h < htab(k)) THEN
      j=k
    ELSE
      i=k
    END IF
    IF (j <= i+1) EXIT
  END DO

  tgrad=gtab(i)                                     ! i will be in 1...NTAB-1
  tbase=ttab(i)
  deltah=h-htab(i)
  tlocal=tbase+tgrad*deltah
  theta=tlocal/ttab(1)                                    ! temperature ratio

  IF (tgrad == 0.0) THEN                                     ! pressure ratio
    delta=ptab(i)*EXP(-GMR*deltah/tbase)
  ELSE
    delta=ptab(i)*(tbase/tlocal)**(GMR/tgrad)
  END IF

  sigma=delta/theta                                           ! density ratio
  RETURN
END Subroutine Atmosphere   ! -----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says, it's doing a binary search. It assumes that the data in htab is sorted, and it is looking for the index of the element that is the same as h. i and j are the lower and upper bounds, and it starts in the middle (i+j)/2. If that element is greater than h, it sets the current index as the upper bound and repeats the loop. Otherwise it sets the lower bound to that index and repeats the loop. The IF test exits the loop when the range is a single element (which may not be h if there is no such element.)

Comment: I should note that this particular piece of code does more work than it has to, in that if it finds an element equal to h it keeps going until it has eliminated all the other greater-or-equal elements. (If there is more than one element with the value of h, you don't know which it will end up with.) It also keeps element k in the lower range even though it has been rejected. Maybe that was intentional, but more typically one exits the search when the target value is found.